# Migration or reposting? How to treat questions reposted here?

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/an-introduction-to-lane-riesenfeld-algorithms) on our site is a reposting by the original poster from [another Stack Exchange site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428101/an-introduction-to-lane-riesenfeld-algorithms) following a recommendation that our site would be a good place to ask.

[This migrated question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/physically-based-rendering-and-ray-tracing) on our site has been moved from Blender Stack Exchange by the official migration process.

Migration means there is still only one question, whereas reposting means the question now exists on both sites. Reposting allows tailoring the wording to the new site, but a migrated question can also be edited to fit.

Should we encourage one approach over the other, or just let things happen as they will?

Is migration always an option, or does its availability vary between different sites?

Comment: In cases where migration is an option, it should be preferred in my opinion. But migration to beta sites should be used carefully. Also see [this recent Meta SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258593/do-the-new-graduation-policies-have-any-effect-on-migrations-to-beta-sites) and maybe also [this quite old Meta SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178444/should-beta-sites-be-listed-for-migration-suggestions) about migration to beta sites.